# C# result type of list after removing nulls from a list of optionals

Tags: c#, linq, option-type

Suppose I have a list of C# optionals (here called `x`), and I create a new list by removing the nulls (here the new list is called `y`)

```
static void Main()
{
    var x = new List<long?> { 7, 8, 9, null, 10, null, 11 };
    var y = x.Where(e => e != null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", y);
}
```

Then the type of `y` is inferred to be `List<long?>`. What is the idiomatic way to get a type of `List<long>`? Explicit unwrapping or explicit casting? Or is there a cleaner way?

In the actual implementation I am dealing with, the values are coming in as lists of optionals, and I need to do convert these lists to sets downstream, so "passing the buck" to subsequent operations is not something I want to do (although I could do lots and lots of null checks later in the code...yuk). I'd really like to have a list-of-longs variable. How is this best thought about and handled in C#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `x.OfType<long>().ToList()` - this will filter out all the nulls and result type will be `List<long>`.

Comment: Although concise, IMO this is an overkill for what it does, because it involves unnecessary boxing and unboxing.

Comment: @IvanStoev that is a very helpful comment. Hard to decide between this answer, which concisely says "just keep all the longs" and Jeroen's answer, which is nicely explicit about taking the unwrapped values where they exist!

Comment: You're right about boxing, but for lists as in example I wouldn't even think about it. Anyway you can always go with `Where->Select` approach.

Answer (score 3):

I would check on the `HasValue` property and select the `Value`

You could try this:

```
var y = x.Where(e => e.HasValue).Select(e => e.Value);
```

With or without the `.ToList()`

Answer (score 3):

I think the best is to create your own extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveNullsAndConvert<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source)
        where T : struct
    {
        return from x in source where x != null select x.Value;
    }
}
```

and then use simply

```
var y = x.RemoveNullsAndConvert();
```

Of course you can use shorter name for the method, and the implementation does not necessarily has to use LINQ - for instance it could be a C# iterator:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> RemoveNullsAndConvert<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> source)
        where T : struct
    {
        foreach (var x in source)
            if (x != null) yield return x.Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Explit cast with Select would do the job:

```
        var x = new List<long?> { 7, 8, 9, null, 10, null, 11 };
        var y = x.Where(e => e != null);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", y);
        IEnumerable<long> z = x.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => (long)e);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", z);
```